# MySQL REGEXP matching positive numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a column varchar[25] with this data inside :

- 886,-886
- -886
- 0,-1234
- 1234
- (empty)
- 0

the numbers might change in size from a 1 digit to a n digits.
and I need to be able to pull any row that has at least one positive number in it

I was thinking that something like

```
REGEXP '[^-,][0-9]+'
```

but this pulls -886 as 88 matches the regexp

Comment: not sure why I didn't think about this before:  `NOT LIKE '%-%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably does not require regex

```
COL not like '-%' AND COL not like '%,-%'
```

however, this is the bad example of storing into incorrect data type,
split `,` and store into multiple rows ...and you can save some time for handling something like this question

Comment: this column can contain even `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-0,1,2,3,4`  that is why multiple columns would not work. a different table would overcomplicate other parts of the code as this column 99% of the times will only contain 0

Comment: @Fabrizio: A view with `GROUP_CONCAT()` might be an option.

Comment: Your post is not the solution, but it helped me to get there: `NOT LIKE  '%-%'` is a very easy way to see if there are negative numbers in a string that might also contain (forgot to mention that) words like "all,-886" or "886,-886"

Comment: OMG, if this case, you can just `REGEXP '-'`! however ... seriously re-think the data-type and how you want to store the data

Answer (score 1):

Try using this :

```
"[^-\d]\d+\b"
```

which should work if i understood your question correctly.

a good regex reference table : http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the best solution:

```
`COL` NOT LIKE  '%-%'
```

I forgot to mention that the column might also contain words like:

- all,-886
- none,886
- 0,1,2,3,none
- 0
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]][^-,][0-9]+[[:>:]]'
```

The `:<:` and `:>:` portions indicate word boundaries.

Comment: interesting, forgot about those.  going to try it

Comment: `REGEXP  '[[:<:]][^-][0-9]+[[:>:]]'` I guess a number is a word boundary. it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

^\b\d+\b$
will give you positive integers.

^[^-]\d+((,([^-]\d+))?)+$
will give you only the lists where all the values are positive integers

For a list with any positive integer (but all valid integers negative or positive) I thinks this will check out:
^((-\d+,)?)+[^-]\d+((,([^-]\d+))?|(,-\d+)?)+$

Here's a great site for Regular Expressions:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

I use it all the time for testing live.